# How to call a PHP script periodically for 1 minute in android and do some action

Tags: php, android, android-asynctask

I am new to android development and i am facing a silly problem, my app is crashing, because i set a timetask to call a URL with httphandler , set it for 1 minute delay .

Is any method to handle it in background ?

Any other method to achieve the same

Comment: If you post your code, it may help.

Answer (score 0):

Do the task which consumes time in the background using [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

**Example:**

```
private class LongOperation extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        // Do background work here
        return "Executed";
    }      

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {               
        //Do something on finish of background work
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
       // Do something before executing doInBackground
    }
}
```

Call this in your activity as:

```
new LongOperation().execute("");
```